# How to express tail index as an expectation (for MaxEnt procedure)

Tags: maximum-entropy, fat-tails

I'm trying to construct a prior probability density function, $f_X(x)$, for a [fat-tailed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution) using the [maximum entropy (MaxEnt) method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy). For my known "testable" information, I have the following information available:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \sigma^2 \\
\text{Tail index} = \alpha,
$$
where the tail index is defined as the exponent $\alpha$ such that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - F_X(x)) \sim kx^{-\alpha},
$$
where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF and $k$ is a proportionality constant.

The MaxEnt procedure requires the $n$ statements of testable information to be of the following form:
$$
\mathbb E [f_i (X)] = F_i, \qquad i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$
It is clear in our case that $f_1(x) = x^2$ and $F_1 = \sigma^2$.

What function $f_2(x)$ satisfies $\mathbb E[f_2(x)] = \alpha$?  Is it possible to formulate the problem in this manner?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it's worth to have a look at the Pareto distribution to have more ideas. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Other_examples) the relevant constraint to find that distribution is a logarithm

Comment: That's going to depend upon which fat-tailed distribution you have, unfortunately.  For the Pareto distribution with minimum value $\theta$, $\mathbb{E}\log(x/\theta) = \alpha$, but for other distributions other relationships would hold instead.